# android:windowBackground="@null" to improve app speed

Tags: android

I just read a [blogpost by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/04/speed-up-your-android-ui/) on how to speed up an app UI. He basically says that if your app uses opaque views you can set the background to `@null` in your `Activity`'s style using:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

Does this work? I was willing to test this using FPS as he did but I didn't find a clear way of getting that info.

I have read some [threads](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/52bb5927f8f5cac3) saying you need to do it yourself.
I am about to add a custom view that draws the FPS in the `onDraw()` method and calls `invalidate()` to get call all the time.

Although this works, I would like to know if there is a better way to analyse FPS in an application.

Comment: That blogpost has a source code of samples. Check `FpsImageView.java`.

Comment: I analyze a FPS first in terms of the range of available weaponry. Games in which you have few guns/knives/whatever and no ability to get others tend to get stale relatively quickly. Then, I focus on ease of navigation -- can I get from point to point without excessive tedium? Configurable HUDs are nice, as I tend to find them  a bit distracting when launching an all-out assault... Oh, wait. You probably mean "frames per second", not "first person shooter". My bad. :-) (and, FWIW, I haven't a clue how you'd calculate FPS outside of a game or custom `View` as you describe).

Comment: @jamapag: Thanks for pointing that out. I got my answer from his code. Would you like to post an answer about it so I can give you the rep points?

Comment: I cannot find any difference in fps of the full screen custom view or Surface view using the no background theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [blogpost](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/04/speed-up-your-android-ui/) has a source code of samples. Check `FpsImageView.java`.

Answer (score 3):

If the UI of your application is completely drawing the window contents, you should always set windowBackground to null.  This prevents the framework from filling your window with the default background color, so it is one less pass that is needed to render each frame which means you can spend your own time drawing that number of pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In relation with how to get the FPS, I was thinking of adding Romain Guy's `activity` code to a class and making my `activities` extend from it while developing to check their FPS. Do you think that is correct? Does it make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on some cases , i've noticed that setting the background to null causes weird ui glitches , as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150761/android-setting-androidwindowbackground-to-null-makes-scrolling-to-smear) .

i would recommend to test it in various devices and on the emulator before deciding to have it .

Comment: As I've read, it seems that weird glitches occur only if both the listView and the window have the background set to @null. If you want to optimize the app, choose either of them.