# Setting android:windowBackground to @null makes scrolling to smear?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

i'm using the sherlock actionbar library in order to support many devices . i have a `viewPager` which has 3 fragments :

- one with a `listView` , each item has a `textView` and an `imageView`
- the second has a `gridView` , each item has a `textView` and an `imageView`
- the third just has a `textView` for now.

as i've heard in google IO videos (and since Lint tells me) , it's recommended to have the next style being used for all of the activities:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

this has worked for me on many devices .

however , on the emulator , using version 2.3.3 , and on galaxy nexus , when i scroll (either the `viewPager` or any of the `adapterViews`) , everything just smears , so i get a lot of white pixels as if nothing was refreshed.

i've even tried to set `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` for all of my adapterViews , but it still occurs.

what is going on? how can i fix this thing ? i like adding the above since it removes the ugly gradient background of galaxy S3 that appears for every app.

Comment: what about a solid black background?

Comment: it wrote an error :"Error: Color types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '#ff000000' ..." ,so i've tricked the compiler and gave it a color from the res folder , and then it worked , but i don't remember what was the reason for the suggestion , so i'm not sure if that helps . all i remember is that romain guy was the one lecturing about it. anyway , why don't you put your answer instead of putting a comment?

Comment: Hmm you know better what you did there to get a solid background, so IMO you should write what you did as answer :)

Comment: i'm not sure it helps , since i don't remember what does this optimization do . i think it's a better way to remove/set the background of the activity than setting it for the layout itself .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should only set the background to nul if you cover it with something else. Either:
- Set the background to null in the theme and add a new background in your layout
or
- Set the background in your theme to the color/image you want.

Comment: btw , why does setting the background on both the listView and the window to null causes the weird smear to occur?

Comment: Because you don't have a background so Android does not clear the window.

Comment: when you say "doesn't clear the window" , does it have anything to do with glClear ? i thought there is a default color of the window to be used.

Comment: There is a default color but when you set the background to null you tell Android to not use it and not draw anything.

Comment: how come this affects only some of the devices , and only for adapterView (at least that's what i saw) ?