# View is not properly refreshed, previous "frame" still appear

Tags: android, gpu

A very strange problem that cause the app to draw ontop of itself without cleaning the previous frame.
Its a bit hard to explain, see the next image:

[image]

Some other symptoms of this problem:

1. If I start it on emulator with GPU, the problem occur.
2. However if I start the emulator without GPU, it does not.
3. The actual device that I use is connected to a monitor using HDMI. Maybe it is related.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a custom layout / ViewGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a very similar problem I've posted before (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150761/setting-androidwindowbackground-to-null-makes-scrolling-to-smear)) .

The problem is that I tried to use 2 tricks for optimization - have an empty background for both the window and its views.

The reason is that there is the window of the activity already has a default background, but when you remove it, and the views don't have a background, Android doesn't "clear" the content with the background, so it smears...

Do note that this "bug" might occur on some devices yet on others it would work fine.

In short, the solution is to set a background to either the window or its views.

Comment: The problem was indeed that the background was not defined (Black is not the default background). Setting it to Black solved this issue. Your answer was very good and helpful, thank you !

Comment: Again, for performance, you can set the background of the window to be null, only make sure that the content (the views) have a background. you can also have the opposite.